# Vue.JS - listen to click on component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm fairly new to Vue.JS and currently having an issue listening to a click event on a component.

JS:

```
Vue.component('photo-option', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            count: 0
        }
    },
    props: ['src'],
    template: `
    <img :src=src v-on:click="$emit('my-event')" />
    `
});
```

HTML:

```
<photo-option :src=uri v-for='uri in aboutUsPhotos' v-on:my-event="foo" />
```

...where `foo` is a method on my main Vue instance.

The above is based on [the Vue.JS docs for handling component events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events), and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The alert doesn't fire, and there's no errors in the console.

Before I found those docs, I also tried simply adding `v-on:click='...'` to both the JS (i.e. the template) and the HTML, each with no success.

What am I doing wrong?

---

[EDIT]

This is happening because the code is picked up by a lightbox script and has its DOM position changed. So presumably the binding/event attachment is being lost.

Does Vue have any way of allowing for this, perhaps by 'reinitialising' itself on an element, or something?

Comment: Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Any library which messes around with the DOM should be avoided with Vue (and React, etc).  Can you find an alternative vue-compatible library?